# Can I ask to be considered for another opening in same group?

Tags: professionalism, negotiation, promotion

I was hired for an Analyst role. A month after my joining, our group published a senior analyst opening. My qualifications (education + work experience) fulfill the criteria mentioned on the website. Can I ask my manager for the other role? If so, how to ask? Should I ask my manager or HR?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Start with your manager. Say you think you're qualified for the senior role and you'd like a promotion. If they don't think it's suitable, you can ask what specific objectives/targets you'd need to achieve over the next 6/12 months to qualify you.

Comment: 100% start with manager. If they have a path for you, or can create a path to a similar role, give them the chance. If they don't, give them the chance to help you follow a path to another team. If you do anything other than "start with manager", you introduce a real risk of creating problems for yourself.

Answer (score 9):

You may find that your company doesn't allow a job change or a promotion for a specific amount of time after joining. This is to prevent the need to do three rounds of interviews to fill two slots. In some companies the hiring software may even block your application as soon as you try to apply.

There is little harm in asking. I would inquire about the procedures, without focusing on your interest in applying.

"Hey boss I see that there is an opening for a senior analyst...is that the type of thing that somebody can get promoted to, or must somebody apply for the senior analysts position."

"Hey boss I see there is an opening for a senior analyst...how long must somebody wait to apply for a new position? Are all applications blocked for 6 months? a year?"

Comment: In the company I work for one generally can post for an opening only after 1 year of service.

Comment: The 1 year rule seems quite typical, and, to a certain extent, also "common sense".

Comment: I once worked for a company where they actively _encouraged_ people to change roles within the company (and I took advantage of this twice). However, they had a one year minimum before applying to change roles, so this does seem likely. However, after only one month as a new hire, there _could_ be some flexibility, especially since it's within the same team and only affects one manager.